# Provide JWT plain tokens to krakend to sign

Tags: fusionauth

I'd like to use fusionauth as a provider of plain JWT tokens to krakend in a similar way as it is described [here](https://www.krakend.io/docs/authorization/jwt-signing/). There seems to be an example leveraging auth0 [here](https://github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-playground).

Is that possible or krakend and fusionauth do not fit together ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this would be possible with FusionAuth. FusionAuth will not issue a token with the `none` algorithm type, but it looks like KrakenD supports JWKS.

Using the OpenID Configuration discovery you can find the JWKS url which KrakenD can use to verify the JWT issued by FusionAuth. See [OpenID Connect endpoints](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints).

The token issuer in this case would the the FusionAuth Login API, or the OAuth2 Password grant. These `POST` requests will return an access token (JWT).

If you run into any issues getting this configured, open an [issue](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues) and we can assist.